# Date sort javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc(objarray) {  
    objarray = objarray.sort(function (a, b) { return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime() });
    alert(objarray);
}
objarray = ["16.08.1993 11:13", "16.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1996 10:12", "08.08.1996 10:12"];
abc(objarray);
</script>
```

Date time format: `dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM`

I want to sort so that I can get the latest date first, but its not working.

Comment: You have `Invalid Date` on `new Date(a).getTime()`. You need parse before compare date

Comment: The date string you're passing is invalid. String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch `a` and `b` and take another string for comparing, like

```
1993-08-16 11:13
```

the [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) data and time format, wich is comparable with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
function abc(objarray) {
    objarray = objarray.sort(function(a, b) {
        function getISO(s) {
            return s.replace(/(..).(..).(....) (.....)/, '$3-$2-$1 $4');
        }
        return getISO(b).localeCompare(getISO(a));
    });
}

var objarray = ["16.08.1993 11:13", "16.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1996 10:12", "08.08.1996 10:12"];
abc(objarray);

console.log(objarray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.getCorrectDate = function () {
    var date = this.split(' ')[0];
    var hours = this.split(' ')[1];

    var dateSplitted = date.split('.');
    return new Date(dateSplitted[2] + '.' + dateSplitted[1] + '.' + dateSplitted[0] + ' ' + hours);
};

var dates = ["16.08.1993 11:13", "16.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1994 11:12", "13.08.1996 10:12", "08.08.1996 10:12"];

var sorted = dates.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.getCorrectDate() - a.getCorrectDate();    
});

alert('First from sorted: '+ sorted[0]);
alert('Last from sorted: '+ sorted[sorted.length - 1]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcq6wqhb/

Javascript's native method `sort` is used to sorting arrays, and we can pass callback function let's say `sorting behavior`([Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)).
But before sorting we need to transform `date` strings to correct format, to be accepted `new Date(dateString)` as parameter, otherwise it gives error `Invalid Date`. 
I'm transorming `dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM` to `yyyy.mm.dd HH:MM` using `getCorrectDate` method

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: If you're going to parse a string to make a Date, pass the parts directly to the Date constructor (e.g. `return new Date(dateSplitted[2], dateSplitted[1]-1, ...)`), don't make another string for the built-in parser to parse, especially one that is known to fail in at least some browsers (see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results))